# Does boat speed affect projectile fire?

Tags: the-last-vikings

I've been having fun with this little android rpg (by Springloaded), trying to protect my crew from projectiles while getting as high a speed as possible.

I have started to wonder if speed actually makes a difference other than shortening my time to a port?  Do fewer projectiles spawn if my boat is going fast enough?

Comment: This question is sadly not about The Lost Vikings, which I was excited to answer.